# XPages: inputRichText in Internet Explorer 11: Controlls does not work

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

i try to use the inputRichText component in internet explorer 11 but it seems that the constrolls to change the font size or font type does not work. 
The problem causes when i work in document mode 9 to edge (default is 7)

Is this an known issue?
Is there a way to round it?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try to use compability mode

Comment: As the default richtext editor in XPages is CKEditor, you can programmatically modify its settings with the global (client-side) JavaScript object named CKEDITOR. I think with CKEDitor.config you can change practically everything about the style of the CKEditors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug where ckeditor doesn't work with IE11 unless you set document mode to IE10. Force IE11 to run as IE10 by using a phase listener with:

```
response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10")
```

For an example phase listener see http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=phase-listener-to-set-ie-to-edge-or-x-ua-compatible-value

Does that help?

Comment: Yes that works, thanks...hopefully ibm will update the ckeditor soon to the current version.

Comment: R9.0.1 FP2 is expected to be out this month which will officially support IE11 with a higher version of CKEditor.

Comment: Thanks MarkyRode for that Information. That would be fantastic